# Seam not injecting Stateful EJB dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, seam, ejb, nullpointerexception

I have not been able to find a solution to this problem and my post to the Seam forum has gone unanswered.  I am hope someone here can help.

I am a noob working with Seam, so I am sure I am just doing something stupid. Any help anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated... I have wasted hours and gotten nowhere. I used the jboss tools to generate a seam project in eclipse. The tool took pre-created JPA entities and created a basic webapp. My first step was to add a registration page so that I can create some users and login using database authentication (I set this up, but will test it once the registration page works). I used the seam-booking example to guide me (basically integrating the form stuff plus additional fields into the view of the seam-gen app). When I test the registration page, I get NullPointerExceptions for all of the injected fields. I have looked through the entire seam-booking example, scoured the web looking at examples, and quickly read through some sections of a book and I do not see where there is any additional configuration information needed. What in the world am I doing wrong? Please help!!!

I am using JBoss Server (community edition) 5.1.0GA and Seam 2.2.0GA.

If you need any more information than what I am posting, please let me know. Thanks to all ahead of time for your help!!

Stateful EJB:

```
@Stateful
@Scope(EVENT)
@Name("register")
public class RegisterAction implements Register {
    @In
    private User user;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @In 
    private FacesMessages facesMessages;

    private String verify = null;

    private boolean registered = false;

    public void registerUser() {
        if (user.getPassword().equals(verify)) {
            List existing = entityManager
                    .createQuery(
                            "select u.userName from User u where u.userName=#{user.userName}")
                    .getResultList();
            if (existing.size() == 0) {
                entityManager.persist(user);
                facesMessages
                        .add("Successfully registered as #{user.userName}");
                registered = true;
            } else {
                facesMessages.addToControl("userName",
                        "Username #{user.userName} already exists");
            }
        } else {
            facesMessages.addToControl("verify", "Re-enter your password");
            verify = null;
        }
    }

    public void invalid() {
        facesMessages.add("Please try again");
    }

    public boolean isRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public String getVerify() {
        return verify;
    }

    public void setVerify(String verify) {
        this.verify = verify;
    }

    @Remove
    @Destroy
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

EJB local interface:

```
@Local
public interface Register
{
   public void registerUser();
   public void invalid();
   public String getVerify();
   public void setVerify(String verify);
   public boolean isRegistered();
   public void destroy();
}
```

XHTML of registratin page:

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">Register</f:facet>
        <h:form id="registration">
            <fieldset><s:decorate id="firstNameDecorate"
                template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">First Name:</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{user.firstName}"
                    required="true">
                    <a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="firstNameDecorate" />
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate> <s:decorate id="lastNameDecorate" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Last Name:</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{user.lastName}" required="true">
                    <a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="lastNameDecorate" />
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate> <s:decorate id="emailDecorate" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Email:</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="emailAddress" value="#{user.emailAddress}"
                    required="true">
                    <a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="emailDecorate" />
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate> <s:decorate id="usernameDecorate" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Username:</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.userName}" required="true">
                    <a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="usernameDecorate" />
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate> <s:decorate id="passwordDecorate" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Password:</ui:define>
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}"
                    required="true" />
            </s:decorate> <s:decorate id="verifyDecorate" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Verify Password:</ui:define>
                <h:inputSecret id="verify" value="#{register.verify}"
                    required="true" />
            </s:decorate>

            <div class="buttonBox"><h:commandButton id="register"
                value="Register" action="#{register.registerUser}" /> &#160; <s:button
                id="cancel" value="Cancel" view="/index.xhtml" /></div>
        </fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Template XHTML (Registration page uses this):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
contentType="text/html">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/favicon.ico"/>
  <a:loadStyle src="resource:///stylesheet/theme.xcss"/>
  <a:loadStyle src="/stylesheet/theme.css"/>
  <ui:insert name="head"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ui:include src="menu.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="projectName" value="MyApp"/>
  </ui:include>
  <div class="body">
     <h:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" styleClass="message"
        errorClass="errormsg" infoClass="infomsg" warnClass="warnmsg"
        rendered="#{showGlobalMessages != 'false'}"/>
     <ui:insert name="body"/>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
     <p>Powered by <a href="http://seamframework.org">Seam</a> #{org.jboss.seam.version} and <a href="http://www.jboss.org/jbossrichfaces">RichFaces</a>. Generated by seam-gen.</p>
     <s:fragment rendered="#{init.debug}">
     <a:log hotkey="D"/>
     <p style="margin-top: -0.5em;">
        Conversation: id = #{conversation.id}, #{conversation.longRunning ? 'long running' : 'temporary'}#{conversation.nested ? ', nested, parent id = '.concat(conversation.parentId) : ''}
        #{' - '}
        Ajax4jsf Log (Ctrl+Shift+D)
        #{' - '}
        <s:link id="debugConsole" view="/debug.xhtml" value="Debug console" target="debugConsole"/>
        #{' - '}
        <s:link id="resetSession" view="/home.xhtml" action="#{org.jboss.seam.web.session.invalidate}" propagation="none" value="Terminate session"/>
     </p>
     </s:fragment>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

Seam Components.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
        xmlns:core="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core"
        xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence"
        xmlns:drools="http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools"
        xmlns:bpm="http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm"
        xmlns:security="http://jboss.com/products/seam/security"
        xmlns:mail="http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail"
        xmlns:web="http://jboss.com/products/seam/web"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation=
            "http://jboss.com/products/seam/core http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools http://jboss.com/products/seam/drools-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/security http://jboss.com/products/seam/security-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/web http://jboss.com/products/seam/web-2.2.xsd
             http://jboss.com/products/seam/components http://jboss.com/products/seam/components-2.2.xsd">

 <core:init debug="true" jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@"/>

 <core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="500"
             conversation-timeout="120000"
             conversation-id-parameter="cid"
             parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid"/>

 <!-- Make sure this URL pattern is the same as that used by the Faces Servlet -->
 <web:hot-deploy-filter url-pattern="*.seam"/>

 <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true"
                  persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/MyAppEntityManagerFactory"/>

 <drools:rule-base name="securityRules">
  <drools:rule-files>
     <value>/security.drl</value>
  </drools:rule-files>
 </drools:rule-base>

 <security:rule-based-permission-resolver security-rules="#{securityRules}"/>

<security:identity-manager identity-store="#{jpaIdentityStore}" />

<security:jpa-identity-store
    entity-manager="#{entityManager}" user-class="my.app.path.dao.profiles.User"
    role-class="my.app.path.dao.profiles.Role" />

 <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">
  <action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}"/>
 </event>
 <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
  <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
 </event>

 <mail:mail-session host="localhost" port="25"/>
</components>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick answer as I'm on the rush:

To address the Seam question first, is "User" a Seam component that will be auto-created or is there a factory method to create one? Annotating a field with @In is just one half of what's required, you still need the other end which supplies the value.

In the bigger picture:

- presuming User is an entity, having it as a Seam component is not a good practice (way too much overhead caused by Seam).
- your stateful bean is scoped as an EVENT. This is unlikely to be your desire, the EVENT scope in Seam is the same as a request for a servlet.

See if you can get a copy of "Seam in Action", it explains the fundamentals very well.

Comment: User is a JPA entity and has the Seam name annotation (i can't remember off the top of my head if it is a scoped entity). I did try a factory and create=true, but that didn't help. I thought that User is instantiated and populated from the registration page data. I have tried SESSION and CONVERSATION scope for the bean, neither worked.  I have EVENT b/c that is what they used in the booking example included with the seam download.  My code really doesn't look any different than the example, which works... so, I am really at a loss. I will definitely take a look at Seam In Action.

Comment: First, realize that @Injected objects are injected before any methods are called on that component. So in this case ask *which* user would be instantiated in this case? I guess you expect an empty instance. To be so, you'd need a method annotated @Factory("user") which creates a new User().

Comment: Check section 4.7.1 of that book for an excellent explanation of how a component is instantiated (or not) or, a little bit less clear, http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e4003

Comment: i will take a look at the reference docs (don't have the book yet).  thanks for the pointers!

Comment: One other thing... we have been focusing on user, which is problematic and may have issues here.  But, what about facesMessages. I thought that this was created by the container and injected for me when annotated with the @In.  This is not one of my own objects and thought it was supposed to be essentially a freebie.  Also, prior to posting for help, I had tried a plethora of things... one of those is the @Factory annotation on a method to create the user. It confuses me greatly how this code is a replica of the booking example, but doesn't work here. Doesn't this suggest a config issue?

Comment: Something is fishy there. Indeed, facesMessages is predefined as an auto-create component in Seam's components.xml. I'm starting to suspect that Seam is not initialized at runtime. Do you see the messages from it in the JBoss log?

Comment: yes, i see all the messages and it looks like everything is loading properly. there is a message stating that it is installing the bean with dependencies and demands and supplies.  interestingly, it shows no dependencies. I will post the log for this as a post rather than a comment.

Comment: Guess I can't do that. here is the log, hopefully it will be readable:
installing bean: jboss.j2ee:ear=DealDataWeb-ear.ear,jar=DealDataWeb-ejb.jar,name=RegisterAction,service=EJB3
 with dependencies:
 and demands:
 jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
 persistence.unit:unitName=DealDataWeb-ear.ear/DealDataWeb-ejb.jar#DealDataWeb
  and supplies:
 jndi:DealDataWeb-ear/RegisterAction/remote
 jndi:DealDataWeb-ear/RegisterAction/local
 Class:net.myproject.web.session.Register
 jndi:DealDataWeb-ear/RegisterAction/local-myproject.web.session.Register

Comment: Those are messages about the EJB container installing the EJBs. I was talking about messages about *Seam* being initialized. Do you have a seam.properties in your jar? Quoting from the docs: Usually, Seam components are installed when the deployment scanner discovers a class with a @Name annotation sitting in an archive with a seam.properties  file or a META-INF/components.xml file. 

I suspect you don't have that and, as such, the Seam nature of your component is not initialized (and, as such, it doesn't even get to be a Seam component, just an EJB).

Comment: I have an empty seam.properties file (same with the booking example). I do have a components.xml file, however. Is this the log entry you are looking for: "Component: user, scope: SESSION, type: ENTITY_BEAN, class: net.myapp.dao.profiles.User"?  Thanks so much for the help with this issue.  I am going to attempt a complete rebuild doing small pieces at a time to see if I introduced a problem by accident. It is clear that whatever is wrong is not at all obvious.

Comment: wishihadabettername... the rebuild fixed the facesMessages, but not the user. this is good, b/c it is probably now just some misunderstanding on my part.  i am stepping back and reading seam in action. i accepted your answer not b/c it fixed all the problems, but put me on the right track. thanks so much for the suggestions, information, and all of your assistance!

Comment: i was wrong... the rebuild fixed nothing.  i am still having the same problem... i have read a good portion of the seam in action book and i am still clueless... i have done everything right and by their example, yet it still doesn't work.  i really don't get it.  could it be a deployment issue? eclipse jboss as plugin deploys to the default/tmp directory... maybe that could be the source of my issue?